# Which version spring security is compatible with spring framework 3.2.6 maven

Tags: spring, spring-security, versions-maven-plugin

I work in a project with Spring framework 3.2.6 and I now have to use spring security. I don't know what version spring security is compatible with spring framework 3.2.6

Answer (score 0):

`spring-security` 3.2.0 is compatible with spring framework 3.2.6

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/3.2.0.RELEASE